# Reading HTML Elements from the Page MVC4

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm sure this a simple question but I have a select html element on my view that is being populated with AJAX JQUERY call after the page loads:

`select id="CategoryList" multiple="multiple" style="width: 212px;"`

This all works fine and dandy but when I try to read the value back to the controller it can't be found, I have tried doing HTTP POSTS and HTTP GETS passing specific parameters or passing FormCollections but I still can't find the item.  In web forms we could mark a html element as runat=server, is there an equivalent thing here that I can just bind the HTML control to the page.

I would use the `@Html.ListBox()` method but I don't have the information in the model to display not do I really want to put this information in the model as it does not make syntactic sense.

This is my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Info(FormCollection collection)
    {
          ...
    }
```

Where `collection.GetValue("CategoryList")` is not part of the form collection.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: You _really_ should be strongly typing your views. It makes all of the fiddly bugs you're experiencing go away..

Comment: One thing that can help troubleshoot problems like this is to watch your raw request in Fiddler or your browser's network tab. If you look at this, you'll see that the value never got posted, which means it definitely won't be part of the `FormCollection`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `name` attribute on the `select` in order to post to the server. Any input field that doesn't have a name doesn't get posted.

If you look at the generated markup that ASP.NET does for you (WebForms and MVC), generally it gives you a field with both an `id` and a `name`, but only the `name` matters when you post.